# Finding median of two sorted arrays of different size

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

I was solving the problem [find median!](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/median-of-two-sorted-arrays-of-different-sizes/)

Here basically I have three doubts:

1. For the case of `N == 1 and M is odd`
   Can't we directly find `MO4( A[0], B[M/2], B[M/2 -1], B[M/2 +1])`?
2. Why are we shortening both arrays `A` *and* `B` by `idxA`?
3. How is time complexity of this algorithm `O(logM + logN)`.

```c++
// A C++ program to
// find median of two sorted arrays of unequal sizes
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

// A utility function to find median of two integers
float MO2(int a, int b)
{ return ( a + b ) / 2.0; }

// A utility function to find median of three integers
float MO3(int a, int b, int c)
{
    return a + b + c - max(a, max(b, c))
                     - min(a, min(b, c));
}

// A utility function to find median of four integers
float MO4(int a, int b, int c, int d)
{
    int Max = max( a, max( b, max( c, d ) ) );
    int Min = min( a, min( b, min( c, d ) ) );
    return ( a + b + c + d - Max - Min ) / 2.0;
}

// Utility function to find median of single array
float medianSingle(int arr[], int n)
{
    if (n == 0)
        return -1;
    if (n%2 == 0)
        return (arr[n/2] + arr[n/2-1])/2;
    return arr[n/2];
}

// This function assumes that N is smaller than or equal to M
// This function returns -1 if both arrays are empty
float findMedianUtil( int A[], int N, int B[], int M )
{
    // If smaller array is empty, return median from second array
    if (N == 0)
        return medianSingle(B, M);

    // If the smaller array has only one element
    if (N == 1)
    {
        // Case 1: If the larger array also has one element,
        // simply call MO2()
        if (M == 1)
            return MO2(A[0], B[0]);

        // Case 2: If the larger array has odd number of elements,
        // then consider the middle 3 elements of larger array
        // and the only element of smaller array.
        // Take few examples like following
        // A = {9}, B[] = {5, 8, 10, 20, 30} and
        // A[] = {1}, B[] = {5, 8, 10, 20, 30}
        if (M & 1)
            return MO2( B[M/2], MO3(A[0], B[M/2 - 1], B[M/2 + 1]) );

        // Case 3: If the larger array has even number of element,
        // then median will be one of the following 3 elements
        // ... The middle two elements of larger array
        // ... The only element of smaller array
        return MO3( B[M/2], B[M/2 - 1], A[0] );
    }

    // If the smaller array has two elements
    else if (N == 2)
    {
        // Case 4: If the larger array also has two elements,
        // simply call MO4()
        if (M == 2)
            return MO4(A[0], A[1], B[0], B[1]);

        // Case 5: If the larger array has odd number of elements,
        // then median will be one of the following 3 elements
        // 1. Middle element of larger array
        // 2. Max of first element of smaller array and element
        //    just before the middle in bigger array
        // 3. Min of second element of smaller array and element
        //    just after the middle in bigger array
        if (M & 1)
            return MO3 ( B[M/2],
                         max(A[0], B[M/2 - 1]),
                         min(A[1], B[M/2 + 1])
                       );

        // Case 6: If the larger array has even number of elements,
        // then median will be one of the following 4 elements
        // 1) & 2) The middle two elements of larger array
        // 3) Max of first element of smaller array and element
        //    just before the first middle element in bigger array
        // 4. Min of second element of smaller array and element
        //    just after the second middle in bigger array
        return MO4 ( B[M/2],
                     B[M/2 - 1],
                     max( A[0], B[M/2 - 2] ),
                     min( A[1], B[M/2 + 1] )
                   );
    }

    int idxA = ( N - 1 ) / 2;
    int idxB = ( M - 1 ) / 2;

    // if A[idxA] <= B[idxB], then median must exist in
    // A[idxA...] and B[...idxB]
    if (A[idxA] <= B[idxB] )
        return findMedianUtil(A + idxA, N/2 + 1, B, M - idxA );

    // if A[idxA] > B[idxB], then median must exist in
    // A[...idxA] and B[idxB...] */
    return findMedianUtil(A, N/2 + 1, B + idxA, M - idxA );
}

// A wrapper function around findMedianUtil().
// This function makes sure that smaller array is
// passed as first argument to findMedianUtil
float findMedian( int A[], int N, int B[], int M )
{
    if (N > M)
        return findMedianUtil( B, M, A, N );

    return findMedianUtil( A, N, B, M );
}

// Driver program to test above functions
int main()
{
    int A[] = {900};
    int B[] = {5, 8, 10, 20};

    int N = sizeof(A) / sizeof(A[0]);
    int M = sizeof(B) / sizeof(B[0]);

    printf("%f", findMedian( A, N, B, M ) );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You present uncommented code - a bad move in general. (You even seem to have deleted comments by hand.) I would have preferred a definition of the value to return with this problem presentation. You dropped `it is assumed that N is smaller than or equal to M`. Please edit your question, and ask specifically _what_ escapes you: that both/all arrays/ranges may be shortened by a value found in just one? That shortening all ranges does simplify the problem?

Comment: @greybeard i am having problem in editing .Can you please check it ?

Comment: Cannot answer as question is on hold still: 1. `MO4( A[0], B[M/2], B[M/2 -1], B[M/2 +1])` equals `MO2(B[M/2], MO3(A[0], B[M/2-1], B[M/2+1]))` knowing that `B[M/2]` is an exact median of `B` it'll always be selected as one of the averaging terms in `MO4`. 2. This is following the divide and conquer paradigm: dividing the problem into subproblems. Here you shorten both arrays by equal amounts towards the median. You cannot halve both arrays as they're not of same size (thus the median wouldn't be in the middle of the range anymore, i.e. making the algorithm return the wrong value).

Comment: I vote to reopen because this is a valid algorithms question in a qualitatively good state.

Comment: There's a related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18790467/median-of-two-sorted-arrays that's only about question 2. @skvatss I suggest you edit your question to only contain 1.

Comment: @BeyelerStudios I got your point.I don't understand people around here instead of helping me to edit the problem as i was not able to do so they just put my valid question on hold.

Comment: @gsamaras   please reopen my question

Comment: (While I think this to be on hold for the wrong reason(s) (consequently giving an unhelpful reference link), visit [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and make this the best question you can. (As [gsamaras](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2411320/gsamaras) has not commented on this question, mentioning his name following a `@` won't get him notified. Far as I remember, editing will notify, hmm, "review"). Anyone can ask for moderator intervention using the "flag" link.) (If it needs spelling out, I think this question needs to be improved before answered.)

Comment: @greybeard I forgot to thank you for the edit and above info is quiet helpful to me. Thanks again.

Comment: @BeyelerStudios: `You cannot halve both arrays […thus…] making the algorithm return the wrong value` ex: {1, 3, 7}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 7, 7, 7, 7}. The "fun" part is that the implementation cited/linked sports factual (if trivial) comments about the half of `B` into which the median would belong to continue to use `idxA` to "shorten `B`" - without spelling out _why_ this (and nothing "notably faster") is correct any more than in the `Remaining Cases:`-paragraph of the description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The two expressions are equivalent knowing that `B[M/2]` is an exact median of `B` (i.e. using `B[M/2-1] <= B[M/2] <= B[M/2+1]`):

   ```
   using a:=A[0], b:=B[M/2], bm:=B[M/2-1], bp:=B[M/2+1]
   MO4(a, b, bm, bp)
   = 0.5 * (a + b + bm + bp - min(a, b, bm, bp) - max(a, b, bm, bp))
   = 0.5 * (b + (a + bm + bp - min(a, bm, bp) - max(a, bm, bp))
   = MO2(b, MO3(a, bm, bp))
   ```
2. This is following the divide and conquer paradigm: dividing the problem into subproblems. Here you shorten both arrays by equal amounts towards the median. You cannot halve both arrays as they're not of same size (thus the median wouldn't be in the middle of the range anymore, i.e. making the algorithm return the wrong value). There are more extensive answers to this [in this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18790467/median-of-two-sorted-arrays).
3. For the case `N <= M` and without loss of generality:

   ```
   T(N, M) :=
   | (N < 2 && M < 2)  O(1)
   | (N < 2 && M >= 2) T(M) = O(log M)
   | (N == 2)          T(M) = O(log M)
   | (otherwise)       1 + T(N - N/2, M - N/2)
   ```

   Here `T(N, M)` is the runtime for `findMedianUtil` and `T(M)` for finding the median in a single array. In general you get `log N` counts until you reach one of the base cases at which point at most `O(log M)` is left -> `O(log N + log M)`.

   As a side note: `O(log M + log N)` is a lazy way of writing `O(log max(N,M))`. For `N <= M` this is equal to `O(log M)` since in that case `O(log N)` is in `O(log M)`.