# Median of two sorted arrays of different length

Tags: algorithm

I am trying to understand the algorithm that solves this problem in O(log(n+m)) where n and m are the lengths of the arrays. I have taken the liberty to post the link to the explanation of this algorithm:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/median-of-two-sorted-arrays-of-different-sizes/

It's so hard for me to digest completely the idea behind this algorithm. I can see that the idea is to reduce the length of one of the arrays to either 1 or 2 and then apply the base cases. The base cases make sense, but I wonder if one can omit the base case for n = 2 and just work on n = 1. I also don't understand the remaining cases part. It looks so weird to me that we have to cut the array B[] from the start to idx. It's weird because idx can be equal to the length of B[], so we would be ignoring the whole array.

Comment: You undestand how binary search works?

Comment: -------------yes, binary search is the art of finding something by halving the data set.

Comment: So look we have array a = "aaaaaaaaaa"  array b = "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb"  if we merge them and sort it would be smth like this "abababbabababbbbababaaba", our goal is to take in each step the most middle part of array so "ababab[babababbbbab]abaaba" <--[this part] is the most middle.  Now we want to make it witthout merging, because merging is O(n), and we can make it in O(logn). SOOOOO in each step we want to throw away half of our elements, and have the middle part. We are taskingg the middle of arrays: 1"aaaaa||aaaaa"2, 1"bbbbbbbbb||bbbbbbbbbb"2, and then we think:

Comment: do we want a1 and a2, a1 and b1, a1 and b2, a2 and b1, a2 and b2, or b1 and b2. So we have 6 posibilities of taking half of elements and we decide by comparing middles, where for sure are our all middle elements

Comment: but some of these cases makes no sense, so we caan skip them

Comment: Possible duplicate of [median of two sorted arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18790467/median-of-two-sorted-arrays)

Comment: @ottomeister equal != different

Comment: I don't see a solution there that's in O(log(n+m)). Can you guide future readers on where to find it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TL;DR:

The main idea is that you may delete N elements that are surely smaller than (or equal to) the median from your number set, as long as you delete the same amount that are surely greater or equal.

Let's explain it with an example:

A=[1 2 3 9 10], B=[3 4 5 6 7 8 9]

The middle elements marked:

A=[1 2 **3** 9 10], B=[3 4 5 **6** 7 8 9]

The overall median will be between 3 and 6, inclusive. So, if we delete two elements smaller than 3, and two elements greater than 6, we'll still have the same median. The smaller elements we delete from A, and the greater ones from B:

A=[3 **9** 10], B=[3 4 **5** 6 7]

Now we delete one element greater than 9 (from A) and one smaller than 5 (from B):

A=[3 9], B=[4 5 6 7]

We reached Case 4 (smaller array has 2 elements): the algorithm calls for the median of

B[M/2], B[M/2 – 1], max(A[0], B[M/2 – 2]), min(A[1], B[M/2 + 1])

being B[2], B[1], max(A[0], B[0]), min(A[1], B[3])

being 6, 5, max(3,4), min(9,7)

being [6 5 4 7]

The median of that array is 5.5. And that's the correct result.

Comment: can we just keep reducing the data sets until the size of one of the arrays is 1? A = [3], B = [5 6 7]

Comment: @Dan You're right, there's no need to stop the algorithm with a two-element array. The B median being 5.5 and the A median being 6, it's perfectly OK to delete the 9 from A and the 4 from B. And finally you can delete the 3 from A and the 7 from B, making A empty, and take the median from B being [5 6].

Comment: @RalfKleberhoff if we go on like you said emptying A and reducing B till 2, then the time complexity will be O(log(max(m,n))) and not O(log(min(m,n)))  ??

Answer (score 0):

```
def findmedian(A,B):
    if len(A) > len(B):
        return findmedian(B,A)# always ensuring that we do the binsearch on the shorter arr
    x = len(A)
    y = len(B)
    start = 0# start and end of shorter arr
    end = x
    while (start <= end):
        partition_x = (start + end)//2# the mid of smaller arr, partition_x is an index
        partition_y = (x+y+1)//2 - partition_x# the suitable partition of larger arr to divide the arrs into equal halves
        if partition_x == 0:# if there is nothing on the left
            left_x = None
        if partition_x == x:# if there is nothing on the right
            right_x = sys.maxint# +inf
        if partition_y == 0:
            left_y = None# this is -inf similar to the case for smaller arr
        if partition_y == y:
            right_y = sys.maxint

        if (left_x <= right_y) and (left_y <= right_x):# all the elems on left are smaller than all the elems on right is ensured by
         #checking on the extremes only since arrs sorted. Also, the partition always makes equal halves, so found the right spot.
            if (x+y) % 2 == 0:
                return (max(left_x,left_y) + min(right_x,right_y))/2.0
            else:
                return max(left_x,left_y)# if the num of elems is odd
            elif left_x > right_y:# if we have come more towards right of smaller arr, then move left on smaller arr
                end = partition_x -1
            else:# if we have come more to the left
                start = partition_x + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Solution:
    def findMedianSortedArrays(self, nums1, nums2):
        nums1.extend(nums2)
        newArray = sorted(nums1)
        
        if len(newArray)%2==0:
            index = len(newArray)//2
            median = (newArray[index] + newArray[index-1])/2
            return float(median)
        else:
            index = len(newArray)//2
            median = newArray[index]
            return float(median)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    obj = Solution()
    print(obj.findMedianSortedArrays([1,3],[2]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
/**
 * @param {number[]} nums1
 * @param {number[]} nums2
 * @return {number}
 */
var findMedianSortedArrays = function (nums1, nums2) {
    let newArray = [];
    let median;

    if (nums1.length > 0 && nums2.length > 0) {
        newArray = [...nums1, ...nums2]
        newArray.sort(function (a, b) {
            return a - b;
        })
    } else if (nums1.length === 0) {
        newArray = nums2
        newArray.sort(function (a, b) {
            return a - b;
        })
    } else if (nums2.length === 0) {
        newArray = nums1
        newArray.sort(function (a, b) {
            return a - b;
        })
    }
    if (newArray.length === 1) {
        return newArray[0]
    }
    if (newArray.length === 3) {
        return newArray[1]
    }

    if (newArray.length % 2 === 0) {
        const findIndex = Math.floor(newArray.length / 2)
        console.log("findIndexeven", findIndex)
        const addValue = Math.max((newArray[findIndex - 1] + 
          newArray[findIndex]), 0)
        median = addValue / 2
    } else {
        const findIndex = Math.floor(newArray.length / 2) + 1
        console.log("findIndexodd", findIndex)
        median = newArray[findIndex - 1]
    }
    console.log("medianValue",median)
    return median
  };

  findMedianSortedArrays([1, 2], [3, 4])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Solution {

public double findMedianSortedArrays(int[] nums1, int[] nums2) {
int m = nums1.length;
int n = nums2.length;

// Make sure nums1 is the smaller array
if (m > n) {
    int[] temp = nums1;
    nums1 = nums2;
    nums2 = temp;
    int tmp = m;
    m = n;
    n = tmp;
}

int iMin = 0, iMax = m, halfLen = (m + n + 1) / 2;
while (iMin <= iMax) {
    int i = (iMin + iMax) / 2;
    int j = halfLen - i;
    if (i < iMax && nums2[j-1] > nums1[i]){
        iMin = i + 1; // i is too small
    }
    else if (i > iMin && nums1[i-1] > nums2[j]) {
        iMax = i - 1; // i is too big
    }
    else { // i is perfect
        int maxLeft = 0;
        if (i == 0) { maxLeft = nums2[j-1]; }
        else if (j == 0) { maxLeft = nums1[i-1]; }
        else { maxLeft = Math.max(nums1[i-1], nums2[j-1]); }
        if ( (m + n) % 2 == 1 ) { return maxLeft; }

        int minRight = 0;
        if (i == m) { minRight = nums2[j]; }
        else if (j == n) { minRight = nums1[i]; }
        else { minRight = Math.min(nums2[j], nums1[i]); }

        return (maxLeft + minRight) / 2.0;
    }
    }
    return 0.0;
}}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    class Solution(object):
      def findMedianSortedArrays(self, nums1, nums2):
      merged_array = (nums1 + nums2)
      merged_array.sort()
      l_m_a = len(merged_array)
      count = int(l_m_a / 2)

      if l_m_a % 2 == 1:
        median = merged_array[count]
        return median
      else:
        median_in_even = (merged_array[count] + merged_array[count - 1]) / 2
        return median_in_even
```

Answer (score -1):

**Median of two sorted Arrays | Same length | Different length**

> 1st we need to merge both arrays in sorted order. And then we can find
> the median. The Median will be the central element of the sorted array.

```
 var findMedianSortedArrays = function(nums1, nums2) {
  let array = [], leftIndex = 0, rightIndex = 0;
  while (leftIndex < nums1.length && rightIndex < nums2.length) {
    if (nums1[leftIndex] < nums2[rightIndex]) {
      array.push(nums1[leftIndex]);
      leftIndex++;
    } else {
      array.push(nums2[rightIndex]);
      rightIndex++;
    }
  }

  // add uninitiated remaining element from either array if any remains. 
  array = array.concat(nums1.slice(leftIndex)).concat(nums2.slice(rightIndex));

  if (array.length % 2 == 0) {
    return (array[(array.length / 2) - 1] + array[array.length / 2]) / 2;
  } else {
    return array[Math.floor(array.length / 2)]
  }
};
findMedianSortedArrays([1 2 3 9 10], [3 4 5 6 7 8 9]);
```

Answer (score -2):

For me, it's just several minutes of several lines of python codes and it passed the leetcode check with a runtime beating 62% of Python3 online submissions. My code is here:

```
class Solution:
    def findMedianSortedArrays(self, nums1: List[int], nums2: List[int]) -> float:
        n = len(nums1) + len(nums2)
        nums1.extend(nums2)  # merge two lists
        nums1.sort()  # sort it
        if n % 2 == 0:
            return (nums1[n//2-1] + nums1[n//2])/2 # return the median for even n
        else:
            return nums1[n//2] # return the median for odd n
```

Comment: Oh, now I know I am wrong. My solution gives a time complexity of O(n log(n)), But the question asks for a solution of O(log (n)).