# How to find the median between two sorted arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm

I'm working on a competitive programming problem where we're trying to find the median of two sorted arrays. The optimal algorithm is to perform a binary search and identify splitting points, `i` and `j`, between the two arrays.

I'm having trouble deriving the solution myself. I don't understand the initial logic.  I will follow how I think of the problem so far.

The concept of the median is to partition the given array into two sets.  Consider a hypothetical `left` array and a hypothetical `right` array after merging the two given arrays. Both these arrays are of the same length.

We know that the median given both those hypothetical arrays works out to be `[max(left) + min(right)]/2`. This makes sense so far. But the issue here is now knowing how to construct the `left` and `right` arrays.

We can choose a splitting point on `ArrayA` as `i` and a splitting point on `ArrayB` as `j`. Note that `len(ArrayB[:j] + ArrayB[:i]) == len(ArrayB[j:] +ArrayB[i:])`.

Now we just need to find the cutting points. We could try all splitting points `i`, `j` such that they satisfy the median condition. However this works out to be `O(m*n) where M is size of ArrayB and where N is size of ArrayA`.

I'm not sure how to get where I am to the binary search solution using my train of thought. If someone could give me pointers - that would be awesome.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48331347/median-of-two-sorted-arrays-of-different-length ?

Comment: I sorta get that. I'm just having trouble going from the O(n*m) solution for searching the i and j coordinates to the O(lgN) solution

Comment: I can reduce it to a single linear scan. We only need to find i because j can be expressed as i plus some constants that we're given.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand the correctness of this approach. How are we certain that such an `i` always exists and there is a unique one?

Answer (score 3):

Here is my approach that I managed to come up with.

First of all we know that the resulting array will contain **N+M** elements, meaning that the left part will contain **(N+M)/2** elements, and the right part will contain **(N+M)/2** elements as well. Let's denote the resulting array as **Ans**, and denote the size of one of its parts as **PartSize**.

Perform a binary search operation on array **A**. The range of such binary search will be [**0**, **N**]. This binary search operation will help you determine the number of elements from array **A** that will form the **left** part of the resulting array.

Now, suppose we are testing the value **i**. If **i** elements from array **A** are supposed to be included in the left part of the resulting array, this means that **j = PartSize - i** elements must be included from array **B** in the first part as well. We have the following possibilities:

- **j > M** this is an invalid state. In this case it means we still need to choose more elements from array **A**, so our new binary search range becomes [**i + 1**, **N**].
- **j <= M** & **A[i+1] < B[j]** This is a tricky case. Think about it. If the next element in array **A** is smaller than the element **j** in array **B**, this means that element **A[i+1]** is supposed to be in the left part rather than element **B[j]**. In this case our new binary search range becomes [**i+1**, **N**].
- **j <= M** & **A[i] > B[j+1]** This is close to the previous case. If the next element in array **B** is smaller than the element **i** in array **A**, the means that element **B[j+1]** is supposed to be in the left part rather than element **A[i]**. In this case our new binary search range becomes [**0**, **i-1**].
- **j <= M** & **A[i+1] >= B[j]** & **A[i] <= B[j+1]** this is the optimal case, and you have finally found your answer.

After the binary search operation is finished, and you managed to calculate both **i** and **j**, you can now easily find the value of the median. You need to handle a few cases here depending on whether **N+M** is odd or even.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Cool thought process. Thanks for the response!

Comment: You are welcome. If it's what you are looking for, please consider marking it as the answer to your question